# Make the "cite" option on a question shown everywhere on the network

Tags: feature-request, citation

The "cite" option on a question is an option only shown on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Cross Validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), and [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).  To quote @FranckDernoncourt, the "cite" option is:

> To make it easier for people writing research publications or other types of documents to cite Stack Exchange questions or answers. The cite option generates a reference that is easy to cite in TeX, which is often used by researchers (and pretty much always in maths/physics/computer science).  I believe the rationale is only showing cite on SE websites that are more likely to be cited in research publications.

And how do we predict the sites most likely to be cited?  Couldn't we make this available for *all* the sites on Stack Exchange?

Comment: We're happy to turn this on for individual sites as they decide it's warranted but having more buttons can be overly taxing, particularly on sites where the feature wouldn't ever be used - it's like adding snippets to all site - many sites need them, but not all, so we don't turn it on everywhere.